# Jenkins plugins working on winstone but not in tomcat

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Am using 0.6.15 version on two instances of Jenkins. One instance runs on tomcat6 and one on jetty. Wall display works fine on jenkins instance that runs on Jetty. But for the one that runs on tomcat6, i get an internal server error. trace shows Caused by: org.acegisecurity.AccessDeniedException: Please login to access job. I do have admin level privilege. Any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using Winstone or Jetty ?  The title says one but the text says the other.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you were logged in on the Jetty (Winstone ?) version but not on the Tomcat version.  Or maybe you have different levels of security enabled on the two versions ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles : Sorry.. winstone. And I have admin permissions on both and I am logged in too.

Comment: It could be the login like you mentioned. I noticed that even though I have a valid login session, when I click on a build link from a build notification mail, it still asks me to login. How do I make it not throw a login page when i have a valid login session? I think this will solve my issue

Comment: I've seen that login issue before and cleared it by deleting all my browser cookies associated with the Jenkins server.  You could also try just using a different browser.

Comment: Thanks! I cracked it. It was the alias URL which was causing the problem. I logged in using one URL but wall display was trying to display using its alias URL and prompted me to login! Now if I login using alias URL i dont have this issue.